# Simple Vanilla JS Todo app

Tags: javascript, html, css, to-do-list

I'm a Kotlin engineer looking to get into web dev. I thought it'd be fun to make a Todo app w/o help from the internet. Just looking for some critiques and feedback, as I'm new-ish to the language.

Here's the JS, HTML, CSS. Looking for criticism on all of it. No mobile support btw.

JS:

```
class Column {
    
    constructor(elementId, countId) {
        this.items = new Map();
        this.count = this.items.size;
        this.elementId = elementId;
        this.countId = countId;
        this.node = document.getElementById(this.elementId);
        this.countNode = document.getElementById(this.countId);
    }

    updateCount() {
        this.count = this.items.size;
        this.countNode.innerHTML = "|(" + this.count.toString() + ")";
    }
}

class Todo extends Column {

    constructor() {
        super("todo", "todoCount");
    }

    add(item) {
        item.toolbar.appendChild(item.close);

        if (item.complete) {
            item.checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
                closeItem(item);
            });

            item.complete = false;
        }

        this.items.set(item, item.node);
        this.node.appendChild(item.node);
        this.updateCount()
    }

    remove(item) {
        this.items.delete(item);
        item.node.remove();
        item.complete = true;
        this.updateCount();
    }
}

class Done extends Column {

    constructor() {
        super("done", "doneCount");
    }

    add(item) {
        item.checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
            openItem(item);
        });

        this.items.set(item, item.node);
        this.node.appendChild(item.node);
        this.updateCount();
    }

    remove(item) {
        this.items.delete(item);
        item.node.remove();
        this.updateCount();
    }
}

class TodoItem {

    constructor() {
        this.node = null;
        this.toolbar = null;
        this.checkbox = null;
        this.close = null;
        this.complete = false;
    }

    generateName() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000).toString();
    }

    create() {
        // Create the parent of the todo item
        let item = document.createElement("article");
        item.id = this.generateName();

        // Create a checkbox, and its parent
        let todoToolbar = document.createElement("span");
        todoToolbar.className = "todoToolbar";

        let checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.className = "checkbox";
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";

        let close = document.createElement("span");
        close.className = "close"
        close.textContent = "✖";

        // Create the Todo input area
        let input = document.createElement("textarea");
        input.className = "todoInput";

        checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
            closeItem(this);
        });

        close.addEventListener("click", () => {
            deleteItem(this);
        });

        // Assign children and set the node
        todoToolbar.appendChild(checkbox);
        todoToolbar.appendChild(close);
        item.appendChild(todoToolbar);
        item.appendChild(input);

        this.node = item;
        this.toolbar = todoToolbar;
        this.checkbox = checkbox;
        this.close = close;
    }
}

let todo = new Todo();
let done = new Done();

function closeItem(item) {
    todo.remove(item);
    done.add(item);
}

function openItem(item) {
    done.remove(item);
    todo.add(item);
}

function deleteItem(item) {
    if (done.items.has(item)) {
        done.items.delete(item);
        done.updateCount();
    }

    if (todo.items.has(item)) {
        todo.items.delete(item);
        todo.updateCount();
    }

    item.node.remove();
}

function createItem() {
    let item = new TodoItem();
    item.create();

    todo.add(item);
}

function main() {
    document.getElementById("addTodo").onclick = createItem;
    todo.updateCount();
    done.updateCount();
}

main();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="todoParent">
        <article id="functionality">
            <section id="toolbar">
                <button id="addTodo">Add Todo</button>
            </section>
            <section id="columns">
                <section id="todo">
                    <div class="columnToolbar">
                        <h1>Todo</h1>
                        <h1 id="todoCount"></h1>
                    </div>

                </section>
                <section id="done">
                    <div class="columnToolbar">
                        <h1>Done</h1>
                        <h1 id="doneCount"></h1>
                    </div>

                </section>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

````
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

button {
    z-index: 10;
}

#todoParent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    position:absolute;
}

#functionality {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
}

#columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

#columns h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#columns section {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: black solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 5%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#columns article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 5%;
}

#toolbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#toolbar button {
    margin: 5px;
}

#todoCount {
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.todoToolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.todoCheckbox {
    margin: 5%;
}

.todoInput {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: vertical;
}

.columnToolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

### Too complex

You have over engineered the objects.

`Column` should not care what it contains. All it should do is add and remove items.

Inheriting from `Column` to create `Done` and `Todo` columns has just made more work for the coder.

Only the `Todo` item cares about where it is. It adds it's self to the Todo column if not complete, moves it's self from the todo to done when UI clicked. and removes it's self when deleted.

There should be no calls to outside function to provide this functionality.

### Rewrite

Not addressing various other items the rewrite is an example of a more role driven design. This example does not include any state encapsulation as the focus is on defining clear object roles rather than state safty.

#### Object `Column`

- `new Column(node, countNode);`  Accepts nodes rather than ID's
- `Column.add(item)` adds an item if it has a node to add. It also calls the items added function if item has that function,
- `Column.remove(item)`  Removes the item if it has it.

#### Object `Todo`

- `new Todo()`  Creates nodes and adds listeners and adds its self to the `todoColumn`
- `Todo.added(column)` Called by instance of `Column` to provide a reference to the column
- `Todo.toggleComplete()` Event. Toggles the `complete` semaphore. It removes and adds it's self to the correct column as required.
- `Todo.delete()` Event. Removes it's self from current column,

**Note** that the functions `tag`, `append`, `listener` are just helper functions to reduce the verbosity of DOM API calls.

```js
;(()=>{
"use strict";

const tag = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
const append = (par, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((p, sib) => (p.appendChild(sib), p), par);
const listener = (el, name, call, opt = {}) => (el.addEventListener(name, call, opt), el);

var uid = 0;
class Column {
    constructor(node, countNode) {
        this.items = new Map();
        this.node = node;
        this.countNode = countNode;
    }
    updateCount() { this.countNode.textContent = " | (" + this.items.size + ")" }
    add(item) {
        if (item.node) {
            item?.added(this);
            this.items.set(item, item.node);
            this.node.appendChild(item.node);
            this.updateCount();
        }
    }
    remove(item) {
        if (this.items.has(item)) {
            this.items.delete(item);
            item.node.remove();
            this.updateCount();
        }
    }       
}

class Todo {
    constructor() {
        this.complete   = false;
        this.node       = tag("article", {id: uid++});
        const toolbar   = tag("span", {className: "todoToolbar"});
        const checkbox  = listener(
            tag("input", {className: "checkbox", type: "checkbox"}),
            "click", this.toggleComplete.bind(this)
        );
        const close     = listener(
            tag("span", {className: "close", textContent: "✖"}),
            "click", this.delete.bind(this)
        );
        
        append (
            this.node,
                append(toolbar, checkbox, close),
                tag("textarea", {className: "todoInput"})
        );
        todoColumn.add(this);
    }
    delete() { this.column.remove(this) }   
    added(column) { this.column = column }
    toggleComplete() {
        this.column.remove(this);
        this.complete = !this.complete;
        (this.complete ? doneColumn : todoColumn).add(this);    
    }
}

const todoColumn = new Column(todo, todoCount);
const doneColumn = new Column(done, doneCount);
listener(addTodo, "click", () => new Todo());

})();
```

```css
#todoParent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    position:absolute;
}

#functionality {
    width: 84%;
    background-color: white;
}

#columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

#columns h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#columns section {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: black solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 5%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#columns article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: white;
    width: 82%;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 5%;
}

#toolbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#toolbar button { margin: 5px; }

#todoCount { margin-left: 1%; }

.todoToolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.columnToolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.close { cursor: pointer; }
.close:hover { color: red; }
```

```html
<main id="todoParent">
    <article id="functionality">
        <section id="toolbar">
            <button id="addTodo">Add Todo</button>
        </section>
        <section id="columns">
            <section id="todo">
                <div class="columnToolbar">
                    <h1>Todo</h1>
                    <h1 id="todoCount"></h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="done">
                <div class="columnToolbar">
                    <h1>Done</h1>
                    <h1 id="doneCount"></h1>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </article>
</main>
```